# Windows 7 Starter To Windows 7 Home Premium Any Time Upgrade Fails

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have an ASUS Eee PCnetbook laptop with OEM Windows 7 Starter

I purchased the any time upgrade key.

I followed the instructions...

Error Message: The upgrade key you entered is fpr an edition of windows that does not work with Windows Anytime Upgrade.  Enter s diferet upgrade key.

Please can you help??

Comment: can you tell us the architectures? e.g. starter x86 (32bit) to x64 (64bit)?

Answer (score 0):

Call the Microsoft number that is listed & they will be able to step you through getting it activated properly.